# What permission is needed to add events in calendar?

Tags: 2013, calendar

I have added "Calendar" web part in my publishing site page. When I log in as "Visitor" then I am unable to add any event in it. So basically visitors cannot add anything in calendar?

What minimum permission shall I give to users so they can add something in calendar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to edit items on any list, a user needs Contribute permissions. These can be granted directly or via a group. To see which users and/or groups have permissions to the specific calendar, [follow these steps](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-help/edit-permissions-for-a-list-library-or-individual-item-HA102833689.aspx). You can also read about permissions in SharePoint 2013 [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219771.aspx).

In your specific case, you should grant the Visitors group "Contribute" permissions.